IS NOT NULL date in sql or compare with raw data
I want to ask a question,
imagine i have this query:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (`patient_id`)) AS `num`
FROM `visits` AS `Visit`
         INNER JOIN `patients` AS `patient` ON `Visit`.`patient_id` = `patient`.`id`
WHERE `Visit`.`doctor_id` = 21293
  AND `Visit`.`office_id` = 14712
  AND `Visit`.`started_at` IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1;

now the query is slow and the started_at is indexed.
if i do this instead :
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (`patient_id`)) AS `num`
FROM `visits` AS `Visit`
         INNER JOIN `patients` AS `patient` ON `Visit`.`patient_id` = `patient`.`id`
WHERE `Visit`.`doctor_id` = 21293
  AND `Visit`.`office_id` = 14712
  AND `Visit`.`started_at` > '2000-01-01'
LIMIT 1;

and use comparison for specifying the nullability of the column, it is getting faster. now i wonder if this is the case for all of my queries and i can use that tactic for all of them. is it faster in all cases?
I didnt try anything im just asking if they know it for a fact

Just look into SQL execution plane in the both cases and compare...

If there is no group by then an aggregation will return one row so limit is pointless.

@P.Salmon it wasnt even my question what you answered

Without table and index definitions it's impossible to answer this properly.

@Charlieface my question is global, is it faster to IS NOT NULL for the date column, or its comparison with some random date

Well I can conceive of many different situations where one is faster than the other, so it really does depend on the exact setup. There is no one blanket statement that one of these is definitely faster. One thing is certain: these two queries don't even give the same result.

If there's an index on the column, the comparison may reduce the rows more than the NULL check, making the query faster.

DISTINCTisn't a function, it's a set quantifier. Simply write COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id) to make code clearer.

It largely depends on your table configuration and your index. If you have a simple index on started_at, then it creates a data-structure under the hood that optimizes your searches upon the indexed field-set. Speed largely depends on how that data-structure is being implemented under the hood and how it handles your scenarios. See this article as an example reference: https://builtin.com/data-science/b-tree-index
Now, you have a first search that checks for not null. We know that null is the unknown and therefore the RDBMS will not be able to properly compare any timestamp with null, see this:
mysql> select now() < null;
+--------------+
| now() < null |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select now() > null;
+--------------+
| now() > null |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select now() = null;
+--------------+
| now() = null |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

so if your indexed graph's nodes are being compared against null, then each of the items will likely be compared to null and that will amount to as many comparisons as many nodes you have whereas your second query will quickly evaluate entire trees of nodes by comparing the root to your search criteria, greatly reducing the number of comparisons.
However, if you define an index on whether a field is null (see this for reference:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/is-null-optimization.html), then the is null or is not null comparisons will be quick.
If you want to make them both quick, then you can create a multiple-column index, the first index criteria checking whether the field is null and the second index criteria would depend upon its value. Then you could filter by
`Visit`.`started_at` IS NOT NULL AND `Visit`.`started_at` > '2000-01-01'

